# Movie where a boy finds his father's diary that takes him to a dark world

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this animated movie when I was younger, it's about a boy whose father is in mental hospital and is traumatized. The boy then finds his diary and reads some dark words and goes to another dark world.
I am not sure but I think that's the plot.

Comment: What words did he read?  What did he see in the dark world?  What was the name of the hospital?  What was the boy's name?  What was the father's name?  Do you remember the names of any other characters?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: When did you see this? Did it look older? Was it animated or live action? Where did you see this and what language was it in? Was it dubbed? And any other random details about characters - colour, hair, clothing...

Comment: `when I was younger` -- how much younger were you? "H. P. Lovecraft and the Frozen Kingdom" kinda matches this but it's from 2016.